# Google Compute Engine firebase is not a module

Tags: python, bash, firebase, google-cloud-platform

trying to use the VM as a server to host some python code but it has a problem with the files import of 'firebase'

Output: `ImportError: No module named firebase`

Has anyone had this or anything like this before?

The file which I'm trying run the app from is (serveme.py):

```
    from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from firebase import firebase
import json
import requests
import os.path

firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://***********.firebaseio.com/')

app = Flask(__name__)




@app.route('/')
def index():
   return 'Method was %s' % request.method

@app.route('/firetest', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

etc etc. It has a problem with the import at line 2.

I am using gunicorn to do

```
gunicorn -w 2 -b :5000 serveme:app
```

Comment: Without seeing how you got the error it is going to be hard to help. Please update your question to include the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing this is the best way to ensure you get help on code-related questions.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen done.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I'm not a Pythonista, so can't be of much help here. Hopefully the code will lead someone else to see what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks for your help, I figured it out in the end!

Comment: Great to hear Miah! And thanks for providing a self-answer (upvoted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

then you're able to do

```
sudo pip install requests
sudo pip install python-firebase
```

Python was already installed, apparently you have to install pip again, brew doesn't like multiple downloads of the same package. So use the easy install for just pip.

Hope this helps someone else if they ever come across this.